# SQL Server Compact 4.0 does not show in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I have applied Visual Studio 2010 SP1 to my VS2010 Pro. My VS version now says 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel.

I then downloaded and installed SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0.

However, I still don't see an option for MS SQL Server Compact 4.0. I only see MS SQL Server Compact 3.5.

How can I use SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 with VS2010?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the tooling and it wil mainly work for web projects. See this blog post: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/01/sql-server-compact-40-released.html

Comment: Ok, installed the tooling. Now I can work with a SQLCE4 database in web apps. But I mainly want to work with SQLCE4 in WPF apps with entity framework. Is this possible?

Comment: I you use edmx, you can use my VS Toolbox add-in to create the edmx in any project type: http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/03/15/sql-server-compact-4-0-tooling-support-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1-and-visual-web-developer-express-2010-sp1.aspx

Just install Windows Web Platform Installer:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Search for "sp1" and find "Visual Studio 2010" anything mentioning "SQL Compact 4.0" - and install it.

Great tool from Microsoft (the Web Platform Installer), I think.